# This php if else code on my website is not working

Tags: php

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('description')) {  ?>
    <?php
    $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $username = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_ID); ?>

    <div class="mm-author-box">
        <figure class="mm-author-box-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar($author_ID, 70); ?>
        </figure>
        <?php if ($author_ID === 4) { ?>
            <div class="mm-author-name">
                <a href="<?php echo "http://google.com" ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mm-author-bio">
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php else { ?>
        <?php if ($author_ID === 9) { ?>
            <div class="mm-author-name">
                <a href="<?php echo "http://yahoo.com" ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mm-author-bio">
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

It is a code to display author name and hyper link it.
From the first if statement if author has a description then go inside
Second if statement: if authors ID is 4 then execute the code below if not then
Else, there is one extra div inside the else statement which is for `<div class="mm-author-box">` which is outside the if statement. 
The problem is that when I put this code it breaks the page.. Only the header of the website loads and the content below it doesn't because i have placed this code in the php file which is a template for the page content.
I think there is some syntax problem coz I used the code without else statement and it worked.

Comment: Do you get any errors? ([enable error reporting PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 1):

You missed to close a curly bracket in the end. Add below line as a last line and try :

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I welcome you, fellow minion!

Comment: :) thank you @Mathlight

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how strict that template engine is, but this could be the problem;

```
<div class="mm-author-bio">
            <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You're closing the div inside the if which was started outside the div. So , place that last `</div>` below the `<?php } ?>` and see if that helps

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('description')) {
    $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $username = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_ID); ?>

    <div class="mm-author-box">
        <figure class="mm-author-box-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar($author_ID, 70); ?>
        </figure>
        <?php if ($author_ID === 4) { ?>
            <div class="mm-author-name">
                <a href="<?php echo "http://google.com" ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mm-author-bio">
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else if ($mh_author_ID === 9) { ?>
            <div class="mm-author-name">
                <a href="<?php echo "http://yahoo.com" ?>"> <?php echo $username; ?> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mm-author-bio">
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
            </div>      
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And as AnkiiG pointed out, you missed a closing tag, which I fixed without knowing while formatting my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `if else` structure is like this,

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('description')) { ?>

    <?php if ($author_ID === 4) { ?>

<?php } ?>
<?php else { ?>
    <?php if ($mh_author_ID === 9) { ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

You're not closing the first `if` statement

Comment: you missed bracket before else. <?php else { ?> check line number 6 in my code.